# Conditional Panel in Shiny doesn't update variables

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a conditional panel in R Shiny but am running into issues with values not being assigned. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
   conditionalPanel(condition="input['input.type']=='Use Example Data'",
     textInput("Label", "Enter the label:", "A"),
     ),
   conditionalPanel(condition="input['input.type']=='Upload Data'",
     textInput("Label", "Enter the label:", "B"),
     )
```

Now, with this code, what I was expecting to happen is if the user selects "Use Example Data" then the default value would be A (which it is), but if the user toggles to "Upload Data" then the default values is still A and not B as I would have expected.  It seems only the first conditional panel stores the values since they have the same name?

A second question, when the user toggles between "Use Example Data" and "Upload Data" the conditional panel does change, but if I replace the value of A with, say, C and then toggle back and forth, the value of C will always be there instead of being reset to A.  Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("type", "Type:",c("Use Example Data","Upload Data"))),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("myui")    
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myui <- renderUI({
    if(input$type == "Upload Data"){
      textInput("Label", "Enter the label:", "B")
    }
    else{
      textInput("Label", "Enter the label:", "A")
    }
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: No it's not.  So far your code does what mine does.  But now, on your shiny app change it to upload data, replace the B with, say, C, and then toggle back and forth between upload data and use example data, and you will see that 1) the default value of label doesn't reset itself at B and 2) no matter what you do, the value of label will always be whatever you input into upload teh example data

Comment: Ok I got you now, does it have to be a `conditionalPanel`? `renderui` is far more flexible

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a conditional panel. conditional panel is just what came up when I googled for a solution so I am open to anything.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: One last question, what if I want it to have multiple text inputs in the if statement.  For example how would I add `textInput("Label", "Enter the label:", "B")` and `textInput("Age", "Enter the age:", "76")` inside the if statement?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.  You can use `tagList()`